Modify Content-Type value in boundary/form data
Is there any way in REST Sharp version 111.3 to modify the Content-Type value inside the form data?
Below is an example outgoing call I captured with Fiddler.  As you can see, the content is JSON (AttributeFormat), but when I add that parameter, it's automatically adding text/plain
var request new RestRequest(options)
....
...
...
request.AddParameter("Arequest","{\"attributeFormat\":\"pdf\"}";

POST https://someurl.com/run HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer adfafd....
User-Agent: RestSharp/111.3.0.0
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml 
Host: someurl.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="215c45a3-b9aa-40f1-9eb5-8ceefb192370"
Content-Length: 204 

--215c45a3-b9aa-40f1-9eb5-8ceefb192370

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=ARequest
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8  <---- says text/plain instead of json!

{"attributeFormat":"pdf"}  <---- added as text!

--215c45a3-b9aa-40f1-9eb5-8ceefb192370--

Thanks for any help
Tried to add a JSON item to the body/form, but the Content-Type inside the boundary keeps listing it as text/plain instead of application/json

The Parameter base class has ContentType property. You can replace AddParameter call with:
var parameter = new GetOrPostParameter("Arequest","{\"attributeFormat\":\"pdf\"}");
parameter.ContentType = "application/json";
request.AddParameter(parameter);

Then, it should work.

'Parameter.ContentType' can only be assigned in an object initializer, or on 'this' or 'base' in an instance constructor or an 'init' accessor

Right, I it seems like a bug. I will try fixing it.

It should work with v111.4.1

Ok, thank you for the assistance

Just tested this and It works.  Thank you..
